# genymotion error while run on virtual box

Tags: android, genymotion, dhcp

i have already setup last version of genymotion-2.9.0 and get that error while running it  on windows 10 pro

[image]

and i read solutions on site and find it's ok with the version VirtualBox-5.1.18-114002-Win and  DHCP server  was like that but problem is still exist

[image]

)

and found this screen when try to run it from virtual box

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please update Virtual box (v5.20) [click here for download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Then restart machine,

Open Genymotion -> start any device.

If your problem solved please mark as answer.